# Does smartgit hide the .git folder

Tags: smartgit

I am wondering if smartgit is "hard wired" to hide the .git folder.  I do not see it in my repository, but I do see other "dot" directories, like, for example, .trialdot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SmartGit is hard-wired to hide the `.git` folder.